# Multiple Lookup Columns return no items CAML Query SharePoint Views

Tags: 2013, list-view, caml, list-view-threshold

I have a document library that has reached it's 5000 view limit and I'm trying to retrospectively create views on indexed lookup columns.

I can successfully return views that are customised in SharePoint Designer to use the Interger Lookup ID. However on queries that exceed 5000 with one column filter I need to filter on an additional lookup and I can't seem to get that to work.

```
<Query>
    <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="500"><FieldRef Name="Project_x0020_Category"/></GroupBy>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu"/></OrderBy>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef LookupId="TRUE" Name="Program"/>
                    <Value Type="Integer">6</Value>
                </Eq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef LookupId="TRUE" Name="Responsible_x0020_Group"/>
                    <Value Type="Integer">9</Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
        </Where>
        </Query>
```

**Update**

In response to a query additional information may be of help pinpointing the issue:

I'm querying a document library that has reached it's 5000 view limit, it is managed by Document sets and the filter data is to be used in the custom document set for each content type.

Comment: Does your `Program` & `Responsible_x0020_Group` are indexed?

Comment: Yes, they are both indexed. The only reason I can see for a problem is that they were indexed after the library reached the threshold (not that it should cause an issue)

Comment: I should say, we temporarily increased the threshold in order to index relevant columns

Comment: Did you get any resolution for your query?

Answer (score 5):

Your caml query should have `<Value Type="Lookup">9</Value>` instead of `<Value Type="Integer">9</Value>`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use below updated code as your CAML query.

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef LookupId='TRUE' Name='Program'/><Value Type='Lookup'>6</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef LookupId='TRUE' Name='Responsible_x0020_Group'/><Value Type='Lookup'>9</Value></Eq></And></Where><GroupBy Collapse='TRUE' GroupLimit='500'><FieldRef Name='Project_x0020_Category'/></GroupBy><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='LinkFilenameNoMenu'/></OrderBy></Query>";
```

**Note:-**

- You can not use `<Query>` parameter if you are using it for `SPQuery.Query`.
- You should use `Lookup` inplace of `integer` to get lookupID
- You should do `GroupBy` & `OrderBy` after Where clause in CAML query.

**CAML Query to get Document Set**

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>Document Set</Value></Eq></Where>
```

Comment: Thanks, in relation to the SPQuery, I'm building this in a List view, correct me if I'm wrong, but is that not why the <Query> is used. How would I go about changing this? I've tried your suggestions and made a bit of progress, I had to also change the scope to Recursive, which outputted a lot of items, however within the document sets the view was still returning no items. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: I have updated my answer & added sample CAML query to get document set. Please try it.

Comment: Can you please confirm me where & for what you are querying? Is my answer helps you to get proper resolution?

Comment: I'm querying a document library that has reached it's 5000 view limit, it is managed by Document sets and the filter data is to be used in the custom document set for each content type. Your answer has given me a different result than my previous tests, however it still hasn't helped me with a complete solution.

Comment: Have you tried CAML Query to get Document Set mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Sorry, you are perhaps misunderstanding, a document set content type has the ability to add a default view to the document set welcome page, when you are in the welcome page a view returns all relevant documents. The problem is that when I use any CAML queries suggested to date it will not return any results within the document set default view (even, strangely, it does seem to return values within a normal list view)

Comment: Now you need to change the threshold values in CA for list item & lookup

Comment: Did you got any resolution?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I've not been in the office and therefore haven't been able to test anymore options. I've still not found a resolution. The CA option isn't appropriate as the farm is very large and this solution needs to be sustainable.

Comment: I checked you scenario. You are using date in your query & it is not getting you the result so you need to convert the date to UTC or ISO format & compare it to query. You will get result based on that date. If possible put that query in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your using two lookupfields, make sure that the two columns are added sepeartely but the second column should not be added as extra column while adding the first column from the same list. it will fix the issue